# Loop in QUOTA and DATE (increment 1 month)

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm having trouble looping to generate a table with the QUOTA and DATA columns.

Where the QUOTA is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..
And DATE is for example: 2017-02-13, 2007-03-13, 2017-04-13

```
<?php 
            $parc = 0;
            $newdate = $date;

            for($j = 0; $j<$quota; $j++){

            $parc++;
            $newdate2 = strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($newdate));

            ?>
            <tr>

            <td><?= $parc?></td> 
            <td>--</td> 
            <td>--</td>
            <td>--</td>
            <td>--</td>
            <td>--</td>
            <td><?= date('d/m/Y', $newdate2)?></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$start_date = strtotime("2017-01-01");
$interval = 1;
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>QUOTA</th><th>DATE</th></tr>";
for ($i = 0; $i <12; $i += $interval) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . ($i+1) . "</td><td>" . date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+" . $i . " month", $start_date)) . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Output:

```html
<table border='1'><tr><th>QUOTA</th><th>DATE</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>01/01/2017</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>01/02/2017</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>01/03/2017</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>01/04/2017</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>01/05/2017</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>01/06/2017</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>01/07/2017</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>01/08/2017</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>01/09/2017</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>01/10/2017</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>01/11/2017</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>01/12/2017</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Yes my friend, I was missing the interval